# Convertir string a int

Tags: c++

En este programa tengo que introducir 2 números enteros a y b y el programa debe mostrar por pantalla los números harshad (números que son divisibles por la suma de sus cifras) comprendidos entre a y b. A y b deben ser positivos, y b mayor que a.

En la compilación me dice que hay fallos en el operador `++` del for, y uno de los whiles (no se cuál).

El programa que he utilizado es:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b,n,suma;
    string numero;
    bool harshad;

    harshad = (numero%suma=0);
    cout<<"introduce los numeros a y b:";
    cin>>a>>b;

    while((a<=0)||(b<a){
        cout<<"introduce los numeros a y b:";
        cin>>a>>b;
    }

    for(numero=a;numero<=b;numero++){
        n=0;
        while(numero.at(n)!=0){
            numero.at(n)=numero.at(n)+numero.at(n+1);
        }
    }
    suma=numero.at(n);

    while(harshad=true){
        cout<<numero<<endl;
        numero++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: si formateas, mejor tu codigo ayudaria mas

Answer (score 2):

El primer error, es que en el for no puedes utilizar como contador un string:

```
string numero;
    for(numero=a;numero<=b;numero++){
            n=0;
            while(numero.at(n)!=0){
                numero.at(n)=numero.at(n)+numero.at(n+1);
            }
```

Lo que deberías hacer es crear una variable auxiliar para realizar el for:

```
for(int i=a;i<=b;i++){
    //lo que quieras realizar
}
```

Segundo, en el while estas haciendo una **asignación**, no una **comparación**. Te falto agregar un `=`

```
while(harshad==true){
        // lo que quieras realizar
    }
```

Tercero, te recomiendo que vuelvas a analizar la lógica de tu código, porque posee varios errores.

Saludos

Comment: Te faltó indicar, en el while, que si no se actualiza el valor de `hardshad` dentro del mismo el programa entrará en un bucle sin fin... Y, por favor, arregla tu primer código para poner `string` en vez de `String`